# Nested object changes not reflected in parent object after shallow copy using Object.assign()

Tags: javascript

```js
const mainObj = {
};
const valueChanger = (obj) => {
  if (!obj.data) {
    obj.data = {};
  }

  return (value) => {
    obj.data = { value };
  };
};

let current = valueChanger(mainObj);

mainObj.next = {};
let next = valueChanger(mainObj.next);

current(10);
next(20);
console.log('step:1 ', mainObj);

const nextReference = mainObj.next;

_.each(mainObj, (value, key) => delete mainObj[key]);
Object.assign(mainObj, nextReference);
current = next;
current(21);

console.log('step:2 ', mainObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

After setting data in mainObj, Shallow copying next reference into mainObj by using Object.assign(). After that changes of nested object is not reflecting into mainObj.

Actual Result:

```
{ data: { value: 20 } }
```

Expected Result:

```
{ data: { value: 21 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `valueChanger` to

```js
return (value) {
  obj.data.value = value;
};
```

and it will do what you expect.

Assigning a new object to `obj.data` breaks the previous reference whereas assigning a new value to the `.value` property maintains the same `obj.data` reference which is shared with the parent object.

Comment: Yes @Phil. Until `console.log('step:1 ', mainObj);` line, If i call `current(x)` for n times the changes will reflect into mainObj. After shallow copy by using Object.assign(), the reference has been disconnected. Instead of Object.assign(), If we use normal assign `mainObj = nextReference`, then the problem will be resolved. I don't know exact reason.

Comment: @SKumar sorry, I don't understand your comment